# Will memory usage change between `await Promise.all` and `X = await Promise.all`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

For example, if each of the `promises` resolved with a value that has 1 byte, and the number of promises is 100,000

```js
await Promise.all(promises) // not capture the return value

X = await Promise.all(promises) // capture the return value
```

Obviously, the latter one will cost at least 100,00 byte, but how about the first one?
Will V8 does some optimizations to reduce memory usage for the first one?

Comment: `Promise.all()` doesn't know that its return value is going to be ignored, so it will create the array of results. But the garbage collector might reclaim it quickly.

Comment: It's also not that difficult to make a non-capturing version of `Promise.all()` if you want to test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not assigning the result from `await Promise.all()` just means that the result will be immediately eligible for garbage collection.  The result is still created by `Promise.all()` as it doesn't know whether you're going to use it or not.

So, whether that creates any difference from your `X = await Promise.all(...)` purely depends upon how soon X is available for garbage collection.  If you use the result immediately and then X goes out of scope and is quickly eligible for garbage collection, then there's probably no difference in the memory usage profile as that value will be created and then garbage collected at a similar time either way.

If, on the other hand, `X` stays around for a long time (like gets stored in some lasting data structure) then of course, its memory usage will endure for awhile.

> Will V8 does some optimizations to reduce memory usage for the first one?

No.

Comment: Thanks! You're saying that both of them cost the same memory at some point ? So to save memory, it's better to create a custom version of `Promise.all` so that it won't cumulate the resolved values right..?

Comment: @yaquawa - Even a custom version of `Promise.all()` may or may not help.  If the underlying asynchronous operations are creating the results themselves, then those will be in memory until garbage collected.  It's possible the peak memory usage might be lower with a custom version of `Promise.all()` because the first result back might get garbage collected before the second result arrives and goes into memory.  But, that depends entirely upon the timing of the operations and the timing of GC (both of which are not entirely predictable).

Comment: @yaquawa - You will have the best chance of reducing peak memory usage if you modify the underlying asynchronous operations to never collect the original result in the first place (to never put it in memory at all).  For example, if the result was some JSON that you parse into a Javascript object, then it would be best to never even parse it and never even create that Javascript object.  Or, going even further back in the chain, create an API call that doesn't even send a large result back if you don't want the result.